# Is there such thing like a port forwarding service out in the internet?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, ssl

I'm looking for a service on the internet allowing me to redirect TCP connections.

My company's firewall is very strict and allows only HTTP (through a transparent proxy) or SSL on *only* port 443. I managed to successfully build a tunnel by running `stunnel` on port 443 at home. The problem is: only one service can run on a port at a time! For example I can't run ownCloud and stunnel at the same time. I know I could tunnel SSH in stunnel and tunnel everything through SSH, but it's getting a pain (and multiple tunnels into each other).

If I would run several hosts on the internet (and not my 1 home IP address) I would simply configure IPTABLES to forward the SSL connection to my home IP/any port, and returning packets the other way around. This way I am end-to-end encrypted and simply multiplex services by IP numbers instead of port numbers.

I therefore have two questions:

- Is this possible
- Does it exist

Comment: Did you consider running a SOCKS proxy at home and some kind of redirector at work like [redsocks](http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/)?

Comment: Definitely look into SOCKS proxies.

Comment: What is your company's policy on bypassing the firewall?

Comment: Thanks, SOCKS looks indeed promising. What I also saw was OpenVPN, which should use SSL, too. But I didn't get it working, strange, is the protocol any different from e.g. `stunnel`?

Comment: the firewall is at place for a very good reason. if you value your job do not attempt to bypass it since it most probably violates your company policies and your contract.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SOCKS proxy via ssh - simply run `sshd` on a port you can access (say 443) and then `ssh -D 1080 ...`. `Firefox` can use `SOCKS proxy` native-ly (configuration) to access the internet (except for DNS, but you most likely have that). Other apps can use something like `dante` to socksify them and so on...

Other option is openvpn, squid... the new ssh versions can actually create openvpn-like tunnel (-w).

**NB:** You **should** first consult your system administrator. While you **can** bypass the firewall this way, it is **not very nice**, to say the least ;)

Comment: As mentioned, SSL on port 443 is the only thing. SSH != SSL, so forbidden from the firewall regardless the port. The problem: only stunnel OR https possible, not both.

Comment: That implies level 7 firewall, nice! Buy a beer to your sysadmin for me. It was not very clear... Have you tried `OpenVPN`? It's SSL.